# Sort XML attributes in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, sorting

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2 and the Android Development Tools plug-in. In layouting apps, I use both the Graphical Layout and XML source editors.

After using the graphical editor, I can format the XML source with the XML preferences and `Command+Shift+F`. How do I sort XML attributes alphabetically?

Answer (score 1):

In XML the order of attributes is not significant, so most XML tools assume that they can output attributes in an arbitrary order and the user will not care. Indeed, any downstream processing that depends on the order of attributes is faulty.

I can see that controlling the display order of attributes can be useful for the human reader even if it actually carries no information, but I don't know of any tools that allow you to control this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Yes, human-readability was my goal for that. Hopefully someone can come up with tools to that end.

Comment: The order does have one significent importance -- comparing to previous versions of files to identify changes.

Comment: You should never compare XML documents as text: always use specialist XML comparison tools.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Eclipse ADT 13 will be able to sort your Android XML attributes.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16890